# file upload not working | nginx | php-fpm | MAC | homebrew

Tags: php, macos, nginx

Problem: I try to upload a file to a php script, there $_FILES (which normally is empty with nginx), $_REQUEST. $_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER doesnt contain anything about the uploaded file

NGINX

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.0
built by clang 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx-full/1.6.0 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --sbin-path=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx-full/1.6.0/bin/nginx --with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/include --with-ld-opt=-L/usr/local/lib --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/scgi_temp --http-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log --add-module=/usr/local/share/upload-progress-nginx-module --add-module=/usr/local/share/upload-nginx-module
```

NGINX CONFIG

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  256;
}


http {
    upload_progress uploads 5m;

    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;

    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 1024;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 1024;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    proxy_buffer_size   1024k;
    proxy_buffers   4 1024k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   1024k;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    port_in_redirect off;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;





    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

NGINX VHOST
    server {
        root /var/www/website/public;

```
    location /upload {

        # Pass altered request body to this location
        upload_pass @page;

        # Store files to this directory
        # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
        upload_store /var/www/website/tmp 1;

        # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
        upload_store_access user:rw;

        # Set specified fields in request body
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

        # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_md5" $upload_file_md5;
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_size" $upload_file_size;

        upload_pass_form_field "(.*)";

        ## Track uploads for this location on the zone defined
        ## above with a 60 seconds timeout.
        track_uploads uploads 60s;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.[0-9]+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ $1.$2 break;

        rewrite ^/?(media)/(.+)\.(ogg|ogv|mp3|mp4|ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|swf|pdf) /file.php?name=$1/$2.$3&ext=$3&$query_string last;

        try_files $uri @page;
    }

    location @page {
        rewrite "^(?:/?(?:([\w\-_]+)/?)?(?:([\w\-_]*)/?)?)?" /index.php?page=$1&item=$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV development;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(just in case someone also tries to make fileupload work with nginx...)

after many tries and much research... i will install apache...

the only real working upload module support stopped since nginx 1.3 with no real alternative (the save body to file is also not working, corrupt file, no filename, other post/form parameters are missing)

the only real helping article i found is: https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw

its very disappointing, apache has it i dont know how long maybe since forever, it just works... no configuration needed nothing... just bam..

Answer (score -1):

Add `client_body_buffer_size 10M` to your nginx.conf.

This worked for me.

For reference, I found it here:
http://support.scalr.net/discussions/problems/2045-new-nginx-500-error-on-file-upload-for-files-over-1-mb-in-size-only-on-http